# Equivalent to lapply(a, function(x) x[,1])

Tags: r

Is there a terser equivalent to this code?

```
a <- list(matrix(1,3), matrix(2,3))
lapply(a, function(x) x[,1])
```

I want to fill in the ???

```
lapply(a, `[`, ???)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We need to put the `,` to mimic the row, column index.  Here, we want to get the column and all the rows in that column.  So, we can keep it as blank (`, ,`)

```
lapply(a, `[`, , 1)
```

Suppose, if we want the first row.  Here `[` signifies the extraction operator.  After the comma, we begin with the row/column indexing.  In the below case, we are extracting the first row, so, it should be 1, followed by a `,` that means to get all the column values for that row

```
lapply(a, `[`, 1,)
```

---

Or for a single column `matrix`

```
lapply(a, c)
```

Comment: would you mind explaining in a few words the syntax in the first paranthesis please?

Comment: @GyB  I added some explanations.  Hope it helps